# How do I get a Blocking Assignment signals into Non Blocking Assignment properly in the UVM Driver?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have a query about Blocking Assignment signals into the Non Blocking Assignment properly in the Driver, especially in UVM.

In my example Driver.

```
task run_phase();

vif.addr <=0;

forever begin
    seq_item_port.get_next_item(req);
    //@(posedge vif.CLK);  Need clocking sample to avoid race condition??
    vif.haddr <= req.addr;        
    
    @(posedge vif.CLK iff(vif.READY));

    if(req.rw == READ) begin
        @(posedge vif.CLK iff(vif.READY));
        req.data = vif.hrdata;
    end
    esle
        vif.hwdata <= req.data;
end
```

`req.addr` is assigned to `vif.haddr` without a clocking assignment which means that `vif.haddr` can have multiple values before being sampled at `posedge vif.CLK`.

Should I have to add a clocking sample logic in the every assignment BA to NBA to avoid the race condition or I can ignore?

For the case of example, is this an illegal assignment to avoid race condition, or should I have to add a clocking sample logic `@(posedge vif.CLK);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a synchronous driver, you must always align the driven signals to the clock edge, and you must always use nonblocking assignments.  Doing so is required to avoid race conditions.

```
task run_phase();

vif.addr <=0;

forever begin
    seq_item_port.get_next_item(req);

    @(posedge vif.CLK);
    vif.haddr <= req.addr;        
    
    @(posedge vif.CLK iff(vif.READY));

    // ...
end
```